# Deep filtering in Grouped collection of Entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have the following scheme of Entities:

```
class Container
{
 Forest Forest;
 Tree Tree;
}
class Forest 
{
  int Id;
  string Name;
  List<Trees> Trees;
}

class Tree 
{
 int Id;
 string Name;
 Forest Forest;
 List<Leaf> Leafs;
}

class Leaf 
{
 int Id;
 string Name;
 Tree Tree;
}
```

I have collection of `Forest` with Included `Trees and Leafs` read from database.

How I can do the following:

Filter out collection of `Forests` based on following rule:
 Take Forest entries who either has `[Name]` containing some `"filter value"`
 Or those who has `Trees` `[Name]` containing `"filter value"`
 Or those who's `Leaf` `[Name]` contain `"filter value"`.

I need to return hierarchy of Forest, not flattened view of Forest

I tried flattening the structure to filter entries, like table in database from `INNER JOIN` view

```
IEnumerable<Container> containers;
var groupped = forests.Select(f => new {f.Forest, f.Tree})
  .GroupBy(f => f.Forest)
  .ToList().Select(fs => new {Forest = fs.Key, Leafes = fs.SelectMany(g => g.Tree.Leafes) }).ToDictionary(fx => fx.Forest, fx => fx.Leafes);

var flat = new List<Tuple<Forest, Tree, Leaf>>;
foreach (var i in groupped)
{
 foreach (var l in i.Value) 
 {
  flat.Add((i.Key, l.Tree, l));
 }
}
flat.Where(d => d.Item1.Name.Contains("") 
  || d.Item2.Name.Contains("")
  || d.Item3.Name.Contains(""));
```

But actually here I can't property combine them back to the hierarchy of `Forest -> Tree -> Leaf`

So, instead of having some table-like structure of `List<Tuple<Forest,Tree,Leaf>>` I want to have a normal collection `List<Forest>` with `Trees` and `Leafs` filtered out.

Comment: are you looking to filter it out at the database level or at application level?

Comment: Why does your `Container` class have a `Forest` member and a `Tree` member? What is the significance of the `Tree` member? You say "Filter out collection of Forests" but your code doesn't have a collection of `Forest`s. And what does "with Trees and Leafs filtered out" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can produce a filter collection of `Container` from your list of `Containers` pretty easily, just implement your desired filter exactly as you have written it. (This is not (necessarily) the most efficient way to search, but probably pretty close.)

```
var ans = src.Where(c => c.Forest.Name.Contains(fv) || // Forest name contains filter value
                         c.Forest.Trees.Any(t => t.Name.Contains(fv) || // a Tree name contains filter value
                                                 t.Leafs.Any(l => l.Name.Contains(fv))) // a Leaf name contains filter value
                    );
```

If you hierarchy has few trees and lots of leaves, you may want to change the search to search across trees first, then do a separate tree->leaf search, even though this does two passes through the trees.

```
var ans2 = src.Where(c => c.Forest.Name.Contains(fv) || // Forest name contains filter value
                          c.Forest.Trees.Any(t => t.Name.Contains(fv)) || // a Tree name contains filter value
                          c.Forest.Trees.Any(t => t.Leafs.Any(l => l.Name.Contains(fv))) // a Leaf name contains filter value
                    );
```